# ntdll.dll XX.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, ntdll

I am trying to run this [Example: Plane model segmentation using PCL](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.html) and getting this error.

I found that

pcl::SACSegmentationpcl::PointXYZ seg;

is making this problem.

Any suggestion to fix it.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>

int
 main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  // Fill in the cloud data
  cloud->width  = 15;
  cloud->height = 1;
  cloud->points.resize (cloud->width * cloud->height);

  // Generate the data
  for (auto& point: *cloud)
  {
    point.x = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    point.y = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    point.z = 1.0;
  }

  // Set a few outliers
  (*cloud)[0].z = 2.0;
  (*cloud)[3].z = -2.0;
  (*cloud)[6].z = 4.0;

  std::cerr << "Point cloud data: " << cloud->size () << " points" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& point: *cloud)
    std::cerr << "    " << point.x << " "
                        << point.y << " "
                        << point.z << std::endl;

  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
  // Create the segmentation object
  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
  // Optional
  seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
  // Mandatory
  seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);

  seg.setInputCloud (cloud);
  seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);

  if (inliers->indices.size () == 0)
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset.");
    return (-1);
  }

  std::cerr << "Model coefficients: " << coefficients->values[0] << " " 
                                      << coefficients->values[1] << " "
                                      << coefficients->values[2] << " " 
                                      << coefficients->values[3] << std::endl;

  std::cerr << "Model inliers: " << inliers->indices.size () << std::endl;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < inliers->indices.size (); ++i)
  for (const auto& idx: inliers->indices)
    std::cerr << idx << "    " << cloud->points[idx].x << " "
                               << cloud->points[idx].y << " "
                               << cloud->points[idx].z << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

**Error/Exception:**

```
    Exception thrown at 0x00007FFEDCAFBF18 (ntdll.dll) in planar_segmentation.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
The thread 0x312c has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139).
The program '[31680] planar_segmentation.exe' has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'.
```

Some Info:
VS 2019 16.7.5

Example  Debug 64bit

Win 10 64 bit  system updated

Comment: Does https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies report any issues with your program?